# PostgreSQL xpath to select element having it's child's date attribute as recent

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I have a table history (id int, content xml) in postgreSQL. XML content for one of the id as as following

```
<history-data>
      <history recorded-date="20110601">
        <assignees>
          <assignee>
             <last-name>CIENA LUXEMBOURG</last-name>
          </assignee>
        </assignees>
        <assignors>
          <assignor execution-date="20110517">
              <last-name>NORTEL NETWORKS LIMITED</last-name>
          </assignor>
        </assignors>
      </history>
      <history recorded-date="20110601">
        <assignees>
          <assignee>
              <last-name>CIENA CORPORATION</last-name>
          </assignee>
        </assignees>
        <assignors>
          <assignor execution-date="20110527">
              <last-name>CIENA LUXEMBOURG</last-name>
          </assignor>
        </assignors>
      </history>
      <history recorded-date="20090430">
        <assignees>
          <assignee>
             <last-name>NORTEL NETWORKS</last-name> 
          </assignee>
        </assignees>
        <assignors>
          <assignor execution-date="20090424">
              <last-name>MAK, GARY</last-name>
          </assignor>
          <assignor execution-date="20090424">
              <last-name>VELEZ, EDGAR</last-name>
          </assignor>
        </assignors>
      </history>
    </history-data>
```

Here, i want to get last-name whose execution-date is recent. In this case i want output as **CIENA CORPORATION** as it's execution-date is recent.

I am able to get the first child with the following code but not able to get the element having recent execution-date

```
SELECT id, unnest(CAST(xpath('/history-data/history/assignees[1]/assignee/last-name/text()',content) AS text)::text[]) AS last-name
FROM history
WHERE id = 10
```

Any ideas on how can i do this? In case if there are multiple elements with same execution-date then i want to the first element in xml tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `to_date()` selected `execution-date` text values and get the latest one with `ORDER BY execution-date LIMIT 1`; sample query:

```
SELECT
  unnest(xpath('//assignee/last-name/text()',xml_element)) AS "last-name",
  to_date(unnest(xpath('//assignor/@execution-date',xml_element))::TEXT,'YYYYMMDD') AS "execution-date"
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(xpath('//history',content)) AS xml_element FROM history
  WHERE id = 10
) t
ORDER BY "execution-date" DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Output:

```
     last-name     | execution-date 
-------------------+----------------
 CIENA CORPORATION | 2011-05-27
(1 row)
```